# SwiftUI deleting object from list

Tags: swift, sqlite, swiftui

I have a list of ingredients that is stored in a Sqlite DB and displayed in a list. Users can view an ingredient and edit/delete them. The changes are made in the DB but when returning to the original view the edits are not shown and if an ingredient is deleted and index out of range error occurs

Initial View:

```
@State var ingredients: [Ingredient] = []
var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(self.$ingredients){ ingredientModel in
                //print each ingredient
                IngredientListItem(ingredient: ingredientModel)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            print("Load ingredients from DB")
            self.ingredients = Ingredient_DB().getIngredients()
        })
}
```

Ingredient row:

```
struct IngredientListItem: View {
    @Binding var ingredient: Ingredient
    @State var ingredientSelected: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink (destination: ViewIngredientView(ingredient: $ingredient), isActive: self.$ingredientSelected){
            EmptyView()
        }
        HStack {
            if !ingredient.inStock{Image(systemName: "x.square")}
            Text(ingredient.name)
        }
    }
}
```

view ingredient:

```
struct ViewIngredientView: View {
    @Binding var ingredient: Ingredient
    @State var inStock: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(ingredient.name)
            Text(inStock ? "In Stock" : "Out Of Stock")
            Toggle("", isOn: self.$inStock)
            .onChange(of: inStock, perform: { value in
                //call DB to update ingredient with new values
                ingredient.inStock = inStock
                Ingredient_DB().updateIngredient(idValue: self.ingredient.id.uuidString, nameValue: ingredient.name, inStockValue: ingredient.inStock)
            })
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            //populate on screen
            self.inStock = ingredient.inStock
        })
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button("Delete") {
Ingredient_DB().deleteIngredient(ingredientID: ingredient.id.uuidString)
            }
    }
}
```

when the "inStock" value is changed the value is changed in the database but is not reflected on screen in the list. I can tell the value is changing in the database but the new values are not loaded into the list, the same list of ingredients in displayed.

Comment: Where is the view supposed to be updated when a new value is persisted? I can’t see that part of the code. And why is `id` declared to be a @Binding in ViewIngredientView, is it really supposed to change?

Comment: You have `inStock` declared as `@State`, which means that it is used solely within the view itself, and only can be updated within the view. As the prior comment said, there is no reason for `id` to be a binding. It can be a let constant as you are always ONLY dealing with one ingredient at a time in your `ViewIngredientView`. However, if you want `inStock` to update due to a change in the database, that should be  `@Binding` and injected from the parent views.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your response. I changed ViewIngredientView so that the binding is the Ingredient and the ingredient is passed to it instead of the id. In regards to the first part of your response, are you talking out the initial view? It is only updated when .onAppear is called and I guess that doesn't get called again when the ViewIngredientView is dismissed after deleting?

Comment: @Yrb I changed the id binding like I said in my reply to Joakim. But when you you say inject into parent view, what about when an ingredient is deleted. How can I reflect that in the parent view?

Comment: In SwiftUI you have to think in terms of `State`. If you are using variables that change with `State` (`@State`, `@Binding`, `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject`), the views will redraw when the data changes to reflect that change. Ultimately, in this case, it will come from the `@State var ingredients: [Ingredient]` that you will be passing to the child views. If that changes, it will cause a redraw all the way down due to the `@Binding`. You haven't shown a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can only advise so much.

Comment: @Yrb apologies for the superfluous code, I've cleaned things up. Thank you for your help. I am now able to update the values perfectly but I'm stuck on how to delete the object. Ideally I'd like to just do `ingredient = nil` and have that reflected in the parent view but that doesn't work.

Comment: You haven't shown ANY code on how you do that. MRE is not just about superfluous code, but it is also about necessary code to actually build what you posted. We can't do that here.

Comment: @Yrb Update: I added `id: \.id` to the `ForEach` and now everything works. Not exactly sure why thing made the difference. I will read up on the swiftUI ForEach. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I suspect your data model does not have explicit conformance to `Identifiable`, even though you had `id` defined on it. This is why we needed to see that code as well.